# How can I fix my code to apply it to all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel workbook with almost 70 sheets.
My code is to check the cell(E8) for each sheet and check if same name has folder, so if not to creat it and to go to the next sheet and so on.
But, my code is working only for the 1st sheet.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CreateFolder()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Payslips\" & [E8]

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Path
End If
Next WS
End Sub
```

I need your help please to fix my code to work for all the sheets.

Thank you in advance.
Issa

Comment: You are checking `E8` outside your loop over your sheets. So assign your variable `Path` **inside** your `For Loop` is step 1. Then make sure to work with the `Explicit` reference: `ws.[E8]` =)

Comment: Put: `Path = "C:\Payslips\" & WS.Range("E8")` as the first line INSIDE the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.  I added a check for your root directory, since if it doesn't exist, your code will fail.  Then I moved the Path and cell reference to inside the loop.

```
Sub CreateFolder()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Payslips\"

If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Path
End If

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Len(Dir(Path & WS.Range("E8"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir Path
End If
Next WS
End Sub
```